# Body background blur functionality not working with multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

**Intro** - I have created a modal window wherein multiple modal windows can be opened on top of each other and closed one-by-one Recently i added blur functionality wherein if a modal window is opened , the body background goes blur and if second window is opened , both the body and the first window becomes blur. And it follows same concept while closing ... Closing second window makes first window normal and closing the first window makes the body background normal.

For this particular question , i have created 3 modals - First has a button to trigger it , second can be opened from body of first modal and third modal one has a button

**The blur functionality mentioned in intro is only working well for First & Second modal and doesn't work for third modal - in third modal , closing the modal window doesn't make the body background non blurred like it happens with first 2 modals**

[ The third modal is just a minimal example to explain this issue ,i ideally want this to work with n number of modals ]

Hopefully someone can give a working solution

I am including whole - Html , css and JavaScript codes in snippets , although just to be very specific and easy for you guys , i feel this is part in JavaScript which needs some changes..

```
          if (index > 0) {
            var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
            parentModal.classList.remove("open");
            if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
              parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
            }
          } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }
```

Complete Codes Starts here : ( Js , Html & Css )

```
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

      if (this.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName == 'BODY') {
        document.body.classList.add("open");
      } else {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("open");
      }
    }
  }

  function checkRenableScroll() {
    if (!open_modals.length) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          if (index > 0) {
            var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
            parentModal.classList.remove("open");
            if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
              parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
            }
          } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          if (index > 0) {
            var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
            parentModal.classList.remove("open");
            if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
              parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
            }
          } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<section id="first">

 <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• First Modal</a><br>

<p>Second Modal can be triggered from body of first modal window<br>

<a href="#myModal3" class="modal-button">• Third Modal</a>

</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
             Modal window 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
          <ul><li>You are currently viewing first Modal window
<span class="bold"><a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">Click here to open second modal window</a></span></li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
             Modal window 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
           You are currently viewing Modal window 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
             Modal window 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
           You are currently viewing Modal window 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.open>* {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.modal .open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: As a general rule - I feel it is better to NOT open multiple modals on top of each other - but rather alter your workflow to change the content within the one modal. Just my opinion of course

Comment: @gavgrif yes from that point of view your are correct and i ageee , . I too try to avoid multiple modals unless the content is too long and would look odd in a single long modal where other modals are of the same Standard size ...

Comment: Then I would say that if the content is too much to put into a mlodal - then a modal is not the right tool for the job  and you could have the content in a different page. Regarding the size of the modals - what I would sugest there is to have stylnig on the modal body that is a standard size andp put an overflow onto it. I usually use modal-body { max-height: 75vh; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x: hidden};

Comment: @gavgrif Actually my original intent is to create one website only.   So even with a long content. I don't want users switching to 10 different pages for 10 different sections..  That would increase load time considerably ..so at the end to avoid making the 1 page very long i have resorted to using modals , although i will try your overflow idea.  Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Jquery implementation can get rid of unwanted code under 20 lines (reduced to 17 lines from 100 lines ) and is less complicated.

```
$(function () {
  const openModals = [];
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).show());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')}, 400);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  const openModals = [];
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).show());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')}, 400);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open>* {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.modal .open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="first">
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• First Modal</a><br>
    <p>Second Modal can be triggered from body of first modal window<br>
      <a href="#myModal3" class="modal-button">• Third Modal</a>
  </section>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">Modal window 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
          <ul>
            <li>You are currently viewing first Modal window <span class="bold"><a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">Click here to open second modal window</a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">Modal window 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">You are currently viewing Modal window 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">Modal window 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">You are currently viewing Modal window 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks sir , you are a life saver Your Jquery code working well just one thing. In original JavaScript code , there was a settimeout function to enable downwards sliding Animation while closing modal window which is absent , can you add the relevant Jquery part for that

Comment: Sir i found one other thing too. I had body background scroll disabled in original JavaScript code.   Which is absent in Jquery part -  in Javascript document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 This line was present below the Part where opening of modal is defined and there was a function checkrenablescroll which was being checked while closing of modal window to retain the body scrollabiltiy

Comment: I have added in css `.open {overflow:hidden}`

Comment: sorry my bad just noticed. Can you please lastly just edit the jquery to enable downwards sliding Animation while closing modal window by clicking outside if window/tapping on x icon which was done originally in js using settimeout function

Comment: The css class - .modal-content-active { initiated that Animation while closing modal windows using both ways x icon/clicking outside

Comment: added your animation

Comment: yes sure Jquery is a better implementation and i will mark this as answer so that other people may check this rather than complex vanilla Js codes.  On another note before doing so , your Jquery code needs some last min changes i feel.   If you open and close a modal for first time its okey ,but when you open same modal twice the Animation behaves weirdly.   Check it in action here - https://jsbin.com/vehefebabi/edit?output

Comment: Basically after opening the modal window second time , it unnecessarily shows the closing Animation before opening and while closing , the modal window it lags/delays  a bit

Comment: I have updated the answer. and hey this is getting long. I advise sit down and go thru the jquery api, and start learning and do it yourself. If i keep doing you will never learn. Please mark this as answer and close all threads

Answer (score 1):

Your logic needs revisiting. But if you want to carry on with this, there is a check that you can add to closing

I added a check if there are more modals to close than follow this else close main modal if there is only one. Issue was it was checking on index where it should be checking on number of modals still opened `open_modals.length > 1` with this in addition to your existing logic

```
if (open_modals.length > 1 && index > 0) {
  var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
  parentModal.classList.remove("open");
  if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
    parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
  }
} else {
  document.body.classList.remove("open");
}
```

Working Snippet added below

```js
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

      if (this.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName == 'BODY') {
        document.body.classList.add("open");
      } else {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("open");
      }
    }
  }

  function checkRenableScroll() {
    if (!open_modals.length) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          if (open_modals.length > 1 && index > 0) {
            var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
            parentModal.classList.remove("open");
            if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
              parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
            }
          } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];
          if (open_modals.length > 1 && index > 0) {
            var parentModal = spans[index - 1].parentElement.parentElement;
            parentModal.classList.remove("open");
            if (parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open').length > 0) {
              parentModal.getElementsByClassName('open')[0].classList.remove("open");
            }
          } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.open>* {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.modal .open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="first">

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• First Modal</a><br>

    <p>Second Modal can be triggered from body of first modal window<br>

      <a href="#myModal3" class="modal-button">• Third Modal</a>

  </section>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">
          Modal window 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
          <ul>
            <li>You are currently viewing first Modal window
              <span class="bold"><a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">Click here to open second modal window</a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">
          Modal window 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
          You are currently viewing Modal window 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">
          Modal window 3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
          You are currently viewing Modal window 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  This seem to working well.  Just a heads up you missed that edit of yours in the ..when the user clicks on (x) function   i have understood the fix. Just for someone else visiting this post.  You may add it.

Comment: But you need to revisit the logic for this, else maintaining this would be tough. use full power of jquery if you are including jquery.

Comment: thanks for suggestion , although i am not familiar with Javascript/Jquery.  I think what your telling is to fully rewrite the JavaScript code into a complete Jquery one right ?   Would that be too much work if i ask it on SO as a help ?    ( Have no idea how much lines the codes would be so just confirming from you :)

Comment: i think you can complete this in just under 20 lines